# Error with HOC in Role Based Authorization in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authorization, role-base-authorization, react-hoc

I have been trying implement to [Role Based Authorization in React](https://medium.com/better-programming/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4) as below

In authorization.js, it is checked if the logged-in user with his role, is allowed to access the page or not:

```
import React from "react";

const Authorization = (WrappedComponent, allowedRoles) => {
  return class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        user: {
          name: "vcarl",        
          role: "Admin"
        }
      };
    }
    render() {
      const { role } = this.state.user;
      if (allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      } else {
        return <h1>No page for you!</h1>;
      }
    }
  };
};

export default Authorization;
```

In App.js

```
render() {
    const accounts = Authorization(["SuperAdmin", "Admin"]);

    return (
      <StateContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state }}>
        <Router>                   
            <Route
              exact
              path="/accounts"
              component={accounts(Accounts)}
            />         
        </Router>
      </StateContext.Provider>
    );
  }
```

In Accounts.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Accounts extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Accounts page</div>;
  }
}

export default Accounts;
```

But get the error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor WithAuthorization cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return class 
But in React philosophy component should return JSX or modified Children component
So you need to remove

> `return class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {`

and change line from

> `return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;`

to

> `return <>{this.props.children}</>;`